# Get array value and put it into a variable (multidimensional array?)

Tags: php, arrays, variables

When a `print_r()` an array $stats, I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [like] => 71 [dislike] => 372 [total] => 443 [like_s] => 78 [dislike_s] => 291 [total_s] => 369 [final] => 11 ))
```

I want to get the `[dislike_s]` value and put it into a variable.

I have attempted this:

```
$statss = $stats['dislike_s'];
```

But it did not work. I have also tried `$statss = $stats['dislike_s'][0];` without result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$total_revision[0]['dislike_s']`, the first array index is `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a level of your array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [like] => 71
       //^ this level
```

Also you are using the wrong variable, as you said your array is stored in `$stats` so

```
$total_revision = $stats[0]['dislike_s'];
```

Comment: That was a complete typo, sorry, I was missing the [0] part. thank you, answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$stats is a two dimensional Array, i.e. it is an array of arrays. You can see this from the output of print_r. You have something that looks like `Array ( [0]=>Array(...)). Therefore, when accessing an element of the inside array, you can think of it like this:

```
$inner_array=$stats[0];
$total_revisions=$inner_array['dislike_s'];
```

Php gives you a shorthand for combining these steps(pretty much all languages do) and it looks like `$total_revisions=$stats[0]['dislike_s']` but intuitively it's the same thing. You're saying "in the array $stats[0] give back the value of array element 'dislike_s'"